# Uploaded file going to different directories in Laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel

I'm developing a photo upload using Laravel 7. Here's the code:

```
public function updateProfilePic(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'photo' => 'file|image|max:2048',
    ]);

    if (auth()->user()->photo != 'storage/default-pfp.png') {
        $old_photo = str_replace('storage/', '', auth()->user()->photo);
        try {
            unlink('storage/' . $old_photo);
        } catch (Exception $t) {
            // does nothing
        }
    }

    $path = $request->file('photo')->store('public/profile-pics');
    $res  = $this->user->where('email', auth()->user()->email)->update([
        'photo' => str_replace('public/', 'storage/', $path),
    ]);

    if ($res) {
        return redirect('painel-default');
    } else {
        return redirect('/');
    }
}
```

This works just fine on my computer. The uploaded file goes to storage/app/public/profile-pics. But, when this code runs on my colleague's computer, it goes to storage/app/public/public/profile-pics. Also, other colleague of mine used it to get the same result as mine on his computer. However, out of nowhere, he gets this :storage/app/public/public/profile-pics. We run different php versions 7.4.5, 7.4.8 and 7.4.3 respectively but it doesn't seem to be a problem. Can anyone help me find why is this happening?

Comment: You are already using a framework to avoid rewrite a bunch of things. Why not use all of it? https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem

Comment: I'm quite new at Laravel. You mean that I should use this asset helper to get the file directory?

Comment: Exactly. Use the configuration and functions of Storage facade.

Comment: What is `$this->user`? This is **not** an answer to your question, however, it looks like you're loading the user from the database with `$this->user` using the already loaded user `auth()->user()`. If that is the case then you can just do `auth()->user()->update([...])`.

Comment: Rwd, its the user model. I didnt know that I could do it that way. Thanks.